# Maven install-plugin does not generate jars files for Eclipse Projects included as dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have two Eclipse Maven projects, one of them is referenced by the other project (a dynamic web project) as a dependency. When I export, using Eclipse Export menu, the web project to a war file a jar file is generated for the other project and included in the lib directory in the war file, but when using Maven directly (Run as / Maven Build... / `clean install`) no jar file is generated but only an empty directory with the name `OtherProject.jar`.

Can this be done and I am missing some thing, or is it impossible?

My web project pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Group</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyWarProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.44</version>
    </dependency>

    ...
    other dependencies
    ...

    <dependency>
      <groupId>Group</groupId>
      <artifactId>OtherProject</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

My other project pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Group</groupId>
  <artifactId>OtherProject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestFile>src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    ...
    some dependencies
    ...
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: First keep the conventions and don't change except you exactly know what you are doing..

Comment: Would you be so kind to elaborate a little bit more your comment. I am not a Maven expert and my poms are those generated by Eclipse using the Pom Editor.